# Yii error 404 with all files in place

Tags: php, yii

So I have the following issue... I created a Model with Gii, then I created the CRUD. Paths are right, everything is in place, except I get a 404 Error that the page that I am requesting could not be found...

Any toughs?

**EDIT:**

Called url: http://domain.com/module/controllerId

and the controller code is not altered in any way...

**L.E:** all file permissions and group owners on the server are set correctly

Comment: can you add any code and url you requested?

Comment: unfortunately no, but I have the controller and the views, and everything is wrapped around a module

Comment: add the url you called or how you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

It seams that there is a Apache issue... Somehow, the server will not allow me to have insensitive cases on controllers and/or views, even if 'caseSensitive' field in urlManagement from main.php is set to false...

In this scenario, recreate everything with all lowercases ;)